# Installing Symfony 2 with Virtualbox and Vagrant issue

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, virtualbox

I am not an expert on working with other systems besides my own for my own PHP projects and I have been assigned to make use of different applications now.

I had to install Vagrant and with that I also read I had to install VirtualBox to make it all work. I downloaded a file from Puphpet to help setting up stuff but whenever I type "Vagrant up" I get the following text:

Ruby: No such file or directory -- .../HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems
/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb up (LoadError)

What does this mean? Am I doing something wrong here?

I tried re-installing Vagrant aswell, without result. The same text is still being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had Vagrant installed in a folder with a name containing an apostrophe which caused the error. Anyone ever experiencing this issue aswell, just check the directory's name it.

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to you. There is no obligation to do this.